# Singleton Inheritance C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, reflection, singleton

I was trying to implement a singleton inheritance for my log system, so I would be able to separate the system events from user behavior. I found [this nice post in Java](http://tapas-tanmoy-bose.blogspot.com.br/2013/02/implementation-of-singleton-pattern.html). Despite the Generics difference I could implemente this attached first version (non thread safe for a while).

```
public abstract class Log
{

    private static volatile Dictionary<Type, Log> instances = new Dictionary<Type, Log>();

    public static Log GetInstance(Type type) {

        Log instance = null;
        if (!Log.instances.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            ConstructorInfo ctor = type.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Default,
                    null,
                    new Type[0],
                    new ParameterModifier[0]);

            instance = ctor.Invoke(new object[0]) as Log;
            instances.Add(type, instance);
        }
        else
        {
            instance = Log.instances[type];
        }

        return instance;
    }

    private Log() { }

    public class UserLog : Log
    {
        private UserLog() : base() { }
    }       

    public class SystemLog : Log
    {
        private SystemLog() : base() { }
    }

}
```

The highlight line above shows the attempt to create a new instance. But is doesn't work and returns a null instance of ConstructorInfo.

1) Any ideia about how to use the GetConstructor method? I know it has 3 overloaded versions, but the first one is only for public constructors. If I change the visibility of the constructor to public I can use other overloaded version ([this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h93ya84h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), but this specific version I can't even with public constructors.

2) In C#, is it possible to call a private constructor from other class like I'm trying to do? I have implemented it in Java, but in C# it might be different.

Comment: Singletons have private constructors, so you won't be able to use invoke.

Comment: You can't invoke an abstract class.  Making it a Singleton doesn't make since.

Comment: There is no way to enforce the Singleton requirement on children classes.

Comment: Note because you parent class constructor is private, you can't call the constructor in the child class.  UserLog() : base() {} will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify that the generic type will have to inherit from Log, and that it will have the new(), you can get away with using the parameterless constructor. You also would have to change your constructor to protected so that the child class can call it:

```cs
public abstract class Log
{
    private static volatile Dictionary<Type, Log> instances = new Dictionary<Type, Log>();
    public static TLogType GetInstance<TLogType>() where TLogType : Log, new()
    {
        TLogType instance = null;
        var type = typeof(TLogType);
        if (!Log.instances.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            instance = new TLogType();
            instances.Add(type, instance);
        }
        else
        {
            instance = (TLogType)Log.instances[type];
        }

        return instance;
    }
    protected Log() { }
}
```

I don't think you can call the private constructors outside the class (they are private, after all), but through reflection there may be something that can be done (I'm no reflection expert). Using protected instead of private may get you the results you want.

Answer (score 1):

Since your binding flags don't specify `Private`, you won't get your private constructors. If there were public, you'd need to specify `Public`.

That said, I don't understand your desire to implement this in this way. It seems like a lot of extra work for no good reason.

I would do it like this:

```
public abstract class Log
{
    public class UserLog : Log
    {
        private static readonly Lazy<UserLog> _instance =
            new Lazy<UserLog>(() => new UserLog());
        public static UserLog Instance { get { return _instance.Value; } }
    }

    public class SystemLog : Log
    {
        private static readonly Lazy<SystemLog > _instance =
            new Lazy<SystemLog >(() => new SystemLog ());
        public static SystemLog Instance { get { return _instance.Value; } }
    }
}
```

I.e. just follow the normal singleton idiom for each of the actual singleton classes.

Comment: Thanks Peter!
And how could I store these intances on the Dictionary?

Comment: Why do you want to? In what context do you have a `Type` you can use for the key in the dictionary, but not be able to simply write something like `UserLog.Instance` or `SystemLog.Instance` as appropriate? I.e. how is it that you got a `Type` instance of a singleton object without knowing either the actual type name or having the singleton instance already?